# Azure pricing for sorting or filtering table entities

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am very new to Windows azure. I was just curious how the calculation of number of transactions for sorting or filtering the azure storage tables work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting is not supported on the server, so it certainly isn't billed for. Filtering is not billed in itself, but depending on what you're doing it can influence the number of transactions needed for any given query.

A given transaction can return at most 1000 entities, and that only if they're all on the same partition server. So a very selective filter will result in fewer entities returned, which might require fewer transactions. A non-selective filter (or no filter) may return many entities that will require multiple transactions to retrieve. The number of transactions can also be influenced by the number and size of the partitions, which is controlled by your choice of PartitionKey for your entities.

That said, transactions are dirt cheap at one penny per hundred thousand transactions. It's unlikely that they will be a significant portion of your costs. Don't spend time worrying about transaction costs unless you're very sure you need to.

Comment: Thank you,That answers lot of my doubts. I just have one more, If sorting is not billed for then why do we use azure storage queues? we can just store in the table and sort it according to the time with no cost right? Whereas each pop of a storage queue results in one transaction.

Comment: I guess queues will be faster, but is it worth using queues or just sort the table?

Comment: Generally queues are just easier to use. They already have the queue 
APIs, but using a table as a queue you have to write them yourself. For example, doing a simultaneous pop-and-lock in a table is not possible, AFAIK, so you have to use a more complicated scheme. I think that ease of use makes them worthwhile, unless you really need something that a table-as-a-queue can provide (very long initial visibility delay, 1000 messages in a single pop, etc). BTW, you can get 32 messages in a single queue pop, though you have to delete them individually.